# how can I redirect output from javac back into the calling program

Tags: java, linux, redirect, xterm

```
// this works
if ("Show".equals (obj))
{  
  try {  
    String command= "/usr/bin/xterm -e  javac  panel_1.java"; 
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();      
    Process pr = rt.exec(command);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));    
    String line = null;  
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
      System.out.println(line); 
    }  
  } catch (IOException e)  {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
}
```

This opens an xterm window , calls javac on  panel_1.java, it compiles if  panel_1.java is a valid file. then the xterm window closes. Fine I want to take the warnings, etc., from the compile and put them in a list or a textArea.
Any Ideas???

Comment: Why are you launching xterm? You should be able to use the rt.exec to launch the java compiler itself, which will give you the right input/output stream.

Answer (score 5):

Java 6 has [`JavaCompiler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) from the `javax.tools` package which provides an API to the compiler without the need to run an external process. (read the javadoc I linked!)

[Here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/13/java-se-6-compiler-api/) is a little tutorial on the matter as well.